# Creating sub-datasets and pass it in parallel to cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have data set with 600 rows and 58000; here is what I need to do:

1. Divide the data set into three parts i.e.  25%, 50% and 75% maximum missing values ( I will call it (ai).
2. Each  ai  need to be divide based on the minor allele frequency  ( 0, 0.05, 0.01, 0.1) 
   "  for the definition of minor allele frequency see the attached code “MAF”.
3. For all the combination (3*4)  we need to estimate the missing values using three methods  and then apply specific model for all the combinations (3*4*3).

Now we have 36 data sets.
One of my colleges suggested that we can create 36 directory for all the combinations on the supercomputer (university cluster-Linux) then process each data separately and in the end combine the results.  Any one knows how to do that? I am attaching data set and simple R codes that might make my question a bit clear!
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
   MAF<-function(geno){        ## markers are in the rows
 geno[(geno!=0) & (geno!=1) & (geno!=-1)] <- NA
 geno <- as.matrix(geno)
 ## calc_Freq for alleles
 n0 <- apply(geno==0,1,sum,na.rm=T)
 n1 <- apply(geno==1,1,sum,na.rm=T)
 n2 <- apply(geno==-1,1,sum,na.rm=T)
 n <- n0 + n1 + n2
 ## calculate allele frequencies
 p <- ((2*n0)+n1)/(2*n)
 q <- 1 - p
 maf  <- pmin(p, q)
 frq.index <- maf<=.95 & maf>=.05 ## keep minor allele frequency larger than 0.05
 geno_maf <- geno[frq.index,]
 geno_maf
 }
```